# SQL query to take a MAX value of a field from one row and combine with another row

Tags: sql, rockset

I have some data in [rockset](https://rockset.com/docs/sql-guide/) that, stripped down, looks like this:

| id | userId | lastSession | location | createdAt | completedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'uuid1' | 1 | 1 | 'London' | '2023-01-01' | '2023-01-01' |
| 'uuid2' | 1 | 11 | 'London' | '2023-03-01' | '2023-03-01' |
| 'uuid3' | 1 | 1 | 'Paris' | '2022-07-01' | '2022-07-01' |
| 'uuid4' | 1 | 1 | 'Paris' | '2022-09-01' | '2022-09-01' |
| 'uuid5' | 1 | 11 | 'Paris' | '2022-12-01' | '2022-12-01' |

And what I'm trying to get is a list of rows where the `lastSession=11`, but in the `createdAt` column, I want to show the **highest** `createdAt` date from the same location where the `lastSession=1`.

It is likely there will be multiple lastSession=11's for the same location. So the highest createdAt date should be lower than the nearest lastSession createdAt date if that makes sense. I have added some more detail on the context further below.
For this scaled back example, I am expecting the result to look like:

| id | userId | lastSession | location | createdAt | completedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'uuid2' | 1 | 11 | 'London' | '2023-01-01' | '2023-03-01' |
| 'uuid5' | 1 | 11 | 'Paris' | '2022-09-01' | '2022-12-01' |

But the closest I've got is the above, but instead of showing the createdAt date from the highest lastSession=1 row, it shows the createdAt from the lastSession=1 row using the below query

```
SELECT
    f.id,
    CAST(createdAt AS DATE) as createdAt,
    CAST(createdAt AS DATE) as completedAt,
    f.location
FROM
    mytest f
        INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            id,
            MAX( createdAt ) mid
        FROM mytest
        GROUP BY
            id
    ) g ON f.id = g.id
WHERE
        f.userId = 1
  AND f.lastSession = 11
  AND f.createdAt between CAST("2020-01-01" AS DATE) AND CAST("2023-12-31" AS DATE)
```

Over the last couple of days I've tried many variations, with LEFT JOIN, subqueries and various other tweaks but I'm not sure on where to go from here.

The data is made up of many users, but I'll be passing a userId and a createAt date range, so it's important that the data is taken from a specific user where all createdAt dates are between a set range.

For some context, each record is the user starting and completing an activity that makes up a "run" of sessions for each location, and each session will be started and finished the same day.
A session would start at 1 and going through 2,3,4.. until reaching 11 which would complete that run. However, a user may choose to abandon/reset their current run, meaning they could have multiple lastSession=1 (each new start), before eventually making their way to session 11.
It's important to get the createdAt date of their newest lastSession=1 closest to their next lastSession=11 for the same location, as that lastSession=1 would be their most recent start on that particular location run.

As mentioned at the start, I am using [Rockset's SQL](https://rockset.com/docs/sql-guide/), but I've created a DB fiddle of what I currently have using MySQL at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fuBtQw9tAbzc76bS2owzNf/1

Assume that I cannot change the structure of the data nor make any sort of code-level changes in the program I'm pulling the data into.

Comment: What are you expecting in `createdAt` if no data satisfying the described conditions is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need is a correlated subquery, something like this:

```
SELECT T1.*
,(SELECT MAX(CREATEDAT) 
  FROM MAX_DATE T2 
  WHERE T1.LOCATION = T2.LOCATION 
  AND T2.LASTSESSION = 1) CREATEAT_CALC
FROM MAX_DATE T1
WHERE T1.LASTSESSION = 11
;
```

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what I was looking for! I haven't tried it with a varied set of data, but it works exactly as I wanted using my sample set. You made it look so easy compared to what I was trying to do

Comment: No worries. If it does do what you want then please could you accept my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```sql
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.userId,
    t1.lastSession,
    t1.location,
    max(nvl (t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt)), --nvl here to not return nulls
    CAST(t1.completedAt AS DATE) as completedAt
FROM
    your_table t1
    left join your_table t2 on (
        t2.location = t1.location
        and t2.userId = t1.userId
        and t2.createdAt < t1.createdAt
        and t2.lastSession = 1
    )
WHERE
    f.lastSession = 11
group by
    t1.id,
    t1.userId,
    t1.lastSession,
    t1.location,
    CAST(t1.completedAt AS DATE)
```

In this query, if `createdAt` satisfying the described conditions is not found it is replaced with `createdAt` of the original row.

If `NULL` is preferred - replace the line with `max(t2.createdAt)`